# How to add a modifier to one object in an array and affect all the others

Tags: modifiers

I just modified an object which is part of an array but the changes only affected the object I applied the modifier to.
Is it possible to add a modifier to one of the objects in an array and have that modifier applied to all objects in that array?

Comment: It sounds as if you've already applied the array modifier? If so, each item which was formerly in the array is now a seperate mesh in edit mode. The only way to affect all of them at once is to edit (or add another modifier) before you apply the array.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I had already applied the array and then thought of a modification.    I was afraid of that. I will remove the array, modify the object and add the array again.

Comment: Lesson 1: Don't apply any modifier until you are certain that you've done any adjusting you need to the original object! If you look at any of Josh Gambrill's hard surface modelling videos, you'll see that he rarely applies any modifiers for just that reason! :^)

Comment: You can also duplicate your ojbect before applying the modifiers so you can go back if something goes wrong, and then delete the duplicate once you're sure you won't need it. But I like the Lesson 1 by John Eason above as well. :-)

Comment: @Kyriakh Agreed about keeping a duplicate. Create a new collection called 'Backup' which is disabled and then move any duplicates you've created into it.